# What is SVC CTC on a chart supplement?

Tags: airport, aeronautical-charts, visual-flight-rules, airport-operations, chart-supplement

The chart supplement for KSNA mentions the following

> AIRSPACE: CLASS C svc ctc APP CON svc 1415–0700Z‡ other times CLASS G.

I know that SVC means service. I've gathered that KSNA is class C from 1415 - 0700Z (which is 6:15am - 11pm PDT local time). My questions are the following.

1. It says "svc ctc" and "APP CON svc." What does this mean? My first guess is, both control tower and approach control are in effect. Is that right?
2. What is ctc? Control tower?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FAA Aeronautical Chart Users' Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/SupplementalCharts/UserGuide/) web page has a [link to pdf guide (22MB)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/), lists the abbreviations as follows:

- svc = service
- ctc = contact
- APP = approach control

abbreviation con is not listed.

[Aeronautical Chart Users' Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) web page (no, this is not the same page as above) provides link to a different pdf [(direct link to full guide, 52MB)](https://aeronav.faa.gov/user_guide/20211202/cug-complete.pdf) that provides explanation to abbreviation

- APP CON = approach control

So "svc ctc" would decipher as "for service contact" and latter svc followed by timeframe would inform of applicable service hours of the ATC entity. The whole part in question would thus read "**AIRSPACE CLASS C service contact APPROACH CONTROL, service available 1415-0700 UTC (adjusted for DST); other times CLASS G**".

Comment: Oops, not my area of expertise really... mega something, quite big... I'll fix that in a bit, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91022/which-frequency-to-contact-when-arriving-at-a-class-c-airport-when-the-tower-is -- the present answer, which I suspect is correct, supports the idea that there's no need to contact Approach Control when the airspace is Class G at the surface.